# Excel Line Chart that reports up to current week number from start of the year

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amO2n.png)I have made a series of line charts for my work that compares Budget vs. Actual and year on year sales. I want this to only report up to the current week not the entire year to come. I have made a simple table and created a line chart from it. Is there maybe a rule that I could put into the line graph or on the table itself to limit the information reported to the graph so it only reports up to the current week?

The data currently looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to accomplish this.  Without having to change your existing data table, you can:

1)  Convert your data into an Excel Table (almost always a good idea).
  2)  Add 2 helper columns, chart_actual and chart_yoy.
  3)  Add a formula like this to each column:
    `=IF(ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())<[@Week],NA(),[@Actual])`
    this compares the week number for the current system date in your week column to the ISO week number to determine if the value should be charted or ignored (#n/a).
  4)  Chart your values from the actual_chart and yoy_chart columns.  Any values beyond the current week will be calculated as #n/a and ignored by the chart.

Comment: I have applied the changes that you have given me and yes the line chart doesnt plot the same figures going across after the week in question but it still is showing the rest of the week numbers. As we are in week 2 of the year I want the line chart to just show weeks 1 and 2. Then next week show 1, 2 & 3 etc. Can you shed any light on this? PS I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Just add a similar column for week_chart, so that the the week values beyond what you want charted = #n/a like your actual values.  As your weeks progress, the chart axis will both extend for the additional data.

Comment: Hi Dave Im sorry this is still not working I have put a screen shot onto the initial enquiry. Im wondering if there is something in the chart settings that im not doing?

Comment: Are you using a line chart?  If so, try an XY/Scatter chart. Use the week_chart for the x axis for all series, with your other columns (target, actual, and YOY) for your y axis.  Then, format to taste (e.g. lines, but no markers will appear to be a line chart).

Comment: Brilliant Dave thats it up and working now. You have no idea how thankful I am

Comment: Glad to help.  Since it worked, would mind upvoting and selecting this as the answer (green checkmark)?  Thanks